# Jmeter use _time in consecutive request

Tags: jmeter

i want to create a unique data with time function. below is the code.
Want to use the same unique data in multiple request.

Step1 - JSR223 PostProcessor
long currentTime = ${__time(,)}

Step-2 http request-1
{  "userId": "PerfTesting_${currentTime}"}

Step-3 http request-2
{  "userId": "PerfTesting_${currentTime}"}

But i don't see this is substituting the currenttime variable in requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you have checked the `Cache compiled script if available`

**Solution 1**

> When using this feature, ensure your script code **does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code** as caching would only cache first replacement. Instead, use script parameters.

Hence you need to pass the `${__time(,)}` as a parameter
[image]

**Solution 2**
Just uncheck the `Cache compiled script if available` in your JSR223 Post Processor
[image]

**Solution 3**
You can use [User Parameters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters) Pre-Processor to define the time stamp once per iteration

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into Groovy scripts.

As per [JSR223 Sampler documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler):

> The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance. To benefit from this feature:
>
> - Use Script files instead of inlining them. This will make JMeter compile them if this feature is available on ScriptEngine and cache them.
> - Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.
>
> When using this feature, **ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement.** Instead use script parameters.

So the options are in:

1. Move your __time() function to "Parameters" section and refer it as `Parameters` in the Groovy script like

   [image]
2. Use [System.currentTimeMillis()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) instead of __time() function like:

   [image]
3. You can avoid Groovy scripting at all and just use __time() function:

   - http request-1 `{ "userId": "PerfTesting_${__time(,currentTime)}"}`
   - http request-2 `{ "userId": "PerfTesting_${currentTime}"}`

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)